# Firebase remoteconfig missing methods in java sdk

Tags: java, firebase-remote-config

[Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getString(java.lang.String)) says the following methods are available:

- [getAll](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getAll())
- [getBoolean](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getBoolean(java.lang.String))
- [getDouble](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getDouble(java.lang.String))
- [getLong](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getLong(java.lang.String))
- [getString](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#getString(java.lang.String))

But neither my IDE is seeing them, nor the jar source has them.

[image]

[image]

This is what build.gradle has

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Any clue on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked is for the SDK for client-side Android code, but you're actually including the Admin SDK for use in trusted environments. The documentation for the SDK you include can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/package-summary).